# Crash when using AKNodeOutputPlot and AKNodeRecorder together

Tags: audiokit

I am trying to record while showing a waveform. Here is my code

```
AudioKit.output = AKBooster(gain: 0)
try! AudioKit.start()


audioInputPlot = EZAudioPlot(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100))
let plot = AKNodeOutputPlot(mic, frame: audioInputPlot.bounds)
plot.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
plot.plotType = .rolling
plot.color = UIColor.blue
audioInputPlot.addSubview(plot)

recorder = try! AKNodeRecorder(node: mic)
try! recorder.record()
```

As soon as I start trying to record I get this crash

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: nullptr == Tap()'

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

Both plots and the recorder use the tap feature and you can only have one tap per node. If you want to record the same thing that is being plotted, send the mic to a mixer and then record the mixers out while plotting the mic, or vice versa.

```
mixer = AKMixer()
...
mic >>> mixer >>> booster
...
recorder = try! AKNodeRecorder(node: mixer)
```